# remote mysql will not connect via php/mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Basically I have an application that needs to do a remote mysql connection to get data. I have a local testing mysql server running on an ip like 192.168.1.100 with default ports, and heidiSQL has absolutely no problem connecting. However when I try to do the same with php it takes a long time to load then I get the following error.

```
Connect Error (2003) Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.100' (110)
```

I have triple checked my configuration and see no variance between the login details I use with HeidiSQL and php so this error has me beat. Is there perhaps some sort of php.ini configuration value I have to set to allow remote connections? Google has not been very helpful with this...

Heidi is on my laptop, the mysql server is on a virtual linux server and the server running the script is on a local dedicated machine. They are all within the same network. You might have something there now that I think about it, there is a modem-router attached to the dev server and a router under it acting as a wireless switch. so the firewall on the router could be the cause.

The virtual machine is using a bridged adapter.

UPDATE:
We took the easy way out as this was taking more time then it needed to, so we created a live server to run the mysql server instead of having it local.

To help anyone who has a similar problem I also attempted to forward ports via ssh reverse proxy to bypass any firewall, I was unsuccessful but I can imagine it was just a mistake in the actual command I was doing.

Comment: long pause would indicate something's blocking the connection. firewall? security system?

Comment: In that case I would feel Heidi should have the same problem, but it loads instantly.

Comment: So the PHP code is running on the same machine as Heidi? Remember that user accounts on MySQL are not only username/password, but also source IP based.

Comment: Heidi is on my laptop, the mysql server is on a virtual linux server and the server running the script is on a local dedicated machine. They are all within the same network. You might have something there now that I think about it, there is a modem-router attached to the dev server and a router under it acting as a wireless switch. so the firewall on the router could be the cause.

Comment: You should also check whether your virtual machine is accessible from network, eg. it´s not set to NAT or host-only connection.

Comment: Please kindly add all additional information into the body of your question, so that we do not need to go through the comments to get the full picture.

Comment: @REaction: just because one app can get out doesn't mean another app can as well. firewalls can block on a per-app basis.

Comment: Yea I tried to forward the 3306 port on the router with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"the script is on a local dedicated machine", other than your local machine. Your MySQL is not reachable from your local network, perhaps because of a local firewall (on your physical laptop) or because your virtual machine is NAT'ed.